# Generating JSON on the fly with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery has a `TO_JSON_STRING()` function that converts the result of SQL expressions to json strings. I'm trying to figure out how to use it with a data structure that has a **nested array** represented as a **one-to-many** relationship in BigQuery's tables.

This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT a.account_id, 
  TO_JSON_STRING((SELECT s.skill_id FROM skills s WHERE s.account_id = a.account_id))
FROM accounts a
```

I get this error from BigQuery

> Scalar subquery produced more than one element

The final objective with be to get the `account_id` into the json also, and persisted into a string column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution;

```sql
with accounts as (
  select *
    from unnest([struct(1 as account_id, 'first acc' as account_name)
                ,struct(2 as account_id, 'second acc' as account_name)
                ,struct(3 as account_id, 'third acc' as account_name)
                ])
)
, skills as (
  select *
    from unnest([struct(1 as account_id, 1 as skill_id)
                ,struct(1 as account_id, 2 as skill_id)
                ,struct(1 as account_id, 3 as skill_id)
                ,struct(2 as account_id, 1 as skill_id)
                ,struct(2 as account_id, 4 as skill_id)
                ])
)
, nest as (
  select a.account_id
        ,any_value(a.account_name) as account_name
        ,to_json_string(ifnull(array_agg(s.skill_id ignore nulls),[])) as skills
  from accounts a
  left join skills s
  on a.account_id = s.account_id
  group by a.account_id
)
select *
from nest
```

Output will look like:
[image: sql result]

Comment: Beautiful. Can you include how to add the `account_name` in the json?

Comment: could you try to replacing `*` with `to_json_string(nest)` in the very last of SQL. _And remove first `to_json_string` then._

Comment: That works, but the `to_json_string` above has to be deleted.

Comment: Another way is to replace the one in your answer with `to_json_string(struct(a.account_id as account, ifnull(array_agg(s.skill_id ignore nulls),[]) as skills))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can join it first then generate the json, like this:

```
select TO_JSON_STRING(t) from (select account.account_id as acc_id, skills.* from account inner join skills using(account_id)) as t
```

[image]

Comment: An account can have more than one skill and I want one json per account.